# bower treats git branch and git tag (both lightweight and annotated) distinctly

Tags: git, bower

We have a webapp that includes **our** bower package 'A'.

'A' is a git repo with branches `master` and `develop`. For example `bower.json` of our webapp looks like this:

```
...

devDependencies: {
...

'A': 'http(s)://gitserver:port/A.git#R1.0'
...
}
```

**Goal:**

Our goal is to allow webapp to always point to same tag/branch

**Approaches:**

There are two approaches we could adopt here:

- Using tags (light-weight or annotated)

In bower package `A` we do most merging work on `develop` branch and release `master`. When we are ready to release, we create tag `R1.0` on `master` branch pointing to SHA-commit of `master HEAD`.

In case of any "hotfixes" we push commits to master. Delete tag `R1.0` from local and remote and create tag `R1.0` pointing to new `HEAD` of master.

When the web does a `bower update` we hope it pulls the latest version of bower package 'A'

- Using branches

Cut out a release branch from `master` `HEAD` as  `R1.0`. Upon any "hotfixes", promote them to `master` and then rebase `R1.0` using `master`

`R1.0` branch always holds "releasable" code. In this approach `master` branch is almost like a "dummy" branch

**Problem**:

We observed

```
bower cache clean && bower update
```

only works (refreshes) `bower_components` directory if we used branches approach. i.e. when we use the tags (tried both light-weight and annotated) as described in approach 1 the `bower_components` does not refresh.

Sorry for being so verbose.
Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can create and delete tags at will, I feel they aren't really designed to be moved like that. The first hint at that design is that you can't directly move a tag, but have to delete and re-create it.

When you do move a tag that has already been pushed, other people that fetch changes won't get that updated tag. When such situations arise you should use

```
git fetch origin --tags
```

It will update tags that have been force-pushed to. You'll know the tag has been correctly replaced when you see a log in the console like

```
- [tag update]      v0.1       -> v0.1
```